# Is there a default port for a docker private registry

Tags: docker

This to enable one to use `docker tag image:version docker.mydomain.com/image:version` 
instead of explicitly specifying the port

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`docker pull` (and `push`) [run over HTTPS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-from-a-different-registry), and I believe if you use the default HTTP/TLS port 443 for your server then you won't need to specify it in your image tags.

Answer (score -3):

Actually there is no "default port" the image directs itself to port 5000 internally. It is up to you to map that port when running the container or via a proxy or router to the desired port exposed to the world.

Comment: There is no default for *registry server*, but the *client* by default looks at port 443.